# Replace words in pandas Dataframe using dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas dataframe

```
id  text
1   acclrtr actn corr cr
2   plate corr aff
3   alrm alt
```

and dictionary

```
dict={'acclrtr':'accelerator','actn':'action','corr':'corrosion','cr':'chemical resistant','aff':'affinity','alrm':'alarm','alt':'alternate'}
```

I need to replace dictionary key found in dataframe with its value

I tried following codes, but none of them worked Correctly

1.

```
data['text']=data['text'].str.replace(dict.keys(), dict.values())
```

2.

```
data['text']=data['text'].replace(dict, inplace=True)
```

3.

```
data['text']=data['text'].apply(lambda x: [item.replace(to_replace=dict) for item in x])
```

4.

```
for key, value in dict.items():
    data['text']=data['text'].apply(lambda x: list(set([item.replace(key,value) for item in x])))
```

Can anyone tell me,where I am doing wrong and how to replace key with value properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [108]: data
Out[108]:
   id                  text
0   1  acclrtr actn corr cr
1   2   plate corr affinity   # NOTE: `affinity`
2   3              alrm alt

In [109]: d2 = {r'(\b){}(\b)'.format(k):r'\1{}\2'.format(v) for k,v in d.items()}

In [110]: d2
Out[110]:
{'(\\b)acclrtr(\\b)': '\\1accelerator\\2',
 '(\\b)actn(\\b)': '\\1action\\2',
 '(\\b)aff(\\b)': '\\1affinity\\2',
 '(\\b)alrm(\\b)': '\\1alarm\\2',
 '(\\b)alt(\\b)': '\\1alternate\\2',
 '(\\b)corr(\\b)': '\\1corrosion\\2',
 '(\\b)cr(\\b)': '\\1chemical resistant\\2'}

In [111]: data['text'] = data['text'].replace(d2, regex=True)

In [112]: data
Out[112]:
   id                                             text
0   1  accelerator action corrosion chemical resistant
1   2                         plate corrosion affinity
2   3                                  alarm alternate
```

where `d` - is a replacement dictionary.

PS *don't* use reserved words like (`dict`, `list`, etc) for variable names - it will shadow internal Python types, so you won;t be able to use them properly:

```
In [1]: dict = dict(a='aaa', b='bbb')

In [2]: dict
Out[2]: {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb'}

In [3]: dict2 = dict(c='ccc')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-650e1aa39edb> in <module>()
----> 1 dict2 = dict(c='ccc')

TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

RegEx explanation:

`'(\\b)word(\\b)'` - means search for a word, preceeding and followed by a word boundary and put both word boundaries in capturing groups: first patenthesis - 1st capturing group, etc.

`\\1` - in the substitution part says put there the contents of the *first* cpaturing group (word boundary in our case)

Comment: Thank you MaxU for your answer and suggestion..I dont want `regex=True` because,if I change the 2nd row to `plate corr affinity` I will get output `plate corrosion affinityinity` which I dont want to happen. if I set `regex=False`, replace is not happening.

Comment: @RanjanaGirish, so what do you want to happen to the 2nd row in this case?

Comment: The word _affinity_ should be remain as it is, it should not replace to _affinityinity_ as it has key _aff_ in it.

Comment: @MaxU - I am not good in regex, can you add do question explanation? `\b` is word boundary, but why need `\1` and `\2` ?

Comment: @maxu, replace  is working perfectly, but its taking too much time to execute(for dataset of size 2k its taking 104.07914903743769s in my system with 4gb RAM, is that because of `regex`? can you tell how can I speed up the process ?

Comment: @RanjanaGirish I'm facing the same issue. Were you able to fix this?